# Writing Macro to Save to SQL

Tags: excel, ms-access

I am building a form to store some data and I would like for it to save to a local access table and I am terrible at VBA coding and I was just wondering if anybody had any suggestions for where I should start looking?

Comment: Please, explain more details: source data (where the data comes from?), target table structure,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a typo or two as I don't currently have Excel of Access in front of me but the following should work for you, modify as needed. If you have values for EVERY column of the table you can do the following, if you have only values for specific column you will need to research the Insert Statement to modify it as you need.

```
Sub InsertToAccess()
Dim objConnection As Object  
Dim strInsertSql As String


strInsertSql = "INSERT INTO TableNameHere " &  _
               "VALUES ('ValueForCoumn1', 'ValueForColumn2', 'ValueForColumn3',1)"

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Path\To\Your\Access\File.mdb"

objConnection.Execute strInsertSql 
objConnection.Close
Set objConnection = Nothing 

End Sub
```